# Google BigQuery is running queries slowly

Tags: performance, google-bigquery, large-data-volumes

I'm running a simple bigQuery over my dataset which is about 84GB of log data.

The query takes approx 110 seconds to complete. Is this normal for a data set of this size?

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation, it looks like your table was heavily fragmented. We usually have a coalesce process running to prevent this situation, but it had been off for a couple of weeks while we were verifying a bug fix. I've restarted the coalescer and run it against your table. Please let me know if you continue to see poor performance.

As a best practice, you may be better off importing somewhat less frequently in larger chunks, or splitting your data into time-based tables. BigQuery isn't really designed to handle high-volume small imports to the same table.

Comment: Project id: 326440123436 and the query was just a simple: SELECT timestamp FROM [streaklogsdataset.log_faaf98_00000001353024000000_00000001355616000000] order by timestamp desc LIMIT 1;

Comment: Jordan - any luck investigating the issue?

Comment: Sorry that was a contrived query example. Here's a more realistic one: SELECT errorType, errorTrace, uid, timestamp FROM [streaklogsdataset.log_faaf98_00000001353024000000_00000001355616000000] 
where httpStatus >= 500 order by uid asc, timestamp desc limit 500;

Comment: OK I just looked at your table. It is in 18k fragments. Our coalescer that compacts tables has been paused for a couple of weeks and only recently restarted. Suggestion: run a table copy job to copy it to a new table and use that, or do an export to json and re-import. (we're restarting the coalescer, but it may be 24 hours or so before it catches up).

Comment: OK your table has been fixed. Let me know if you continue to see performance problems with the table.

Comment: The query ran but wasn't exactly fast - it took 82.1 seconds to run.

Comment: Jordan, hi. Is your comment `BigQuery isn't really designed to handle high-volume small imports to the same table` is still valid for 2014 with insertAll functionality that we have now?