# Is there some way to get determine how fragemented a table is?

Tags: google-bigquery

This is related to: [Google BigQuery is running queries slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739160/google-bigquery-is-running-queries-slowly)

I'm trying to determine if some tables that I am using are suffering from this coalescing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no, there is no way to tell how fragmented a tables is. In general, we want to hide this information from users and just do the right thing and coalesce when a table is too fragmented. However, this is something we're considering adding since it could give visibility to issues when they occur.