# BigQuery's query is extremely slow

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 1.6 billion rows.  I have been running a query that uses a group-by field that has over 5 million unique values and then sort by sum of another integer value in descending order and finally return only the top 10.  Notice after more than an hour, that query is still stuck in running state.

I have created this big table by using "bq cp -a  ".  Originally those source tables are "bq cp" from 1000  smaller tables and each table were loaded from over 12 compressed csv load files.

I have searched related question and found "[Google BigQuery is running queries slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739160/google-bigquery-is-running-queries-slowly)" mention slowness caused by fragmentation from a lot of small ingestion. Is my approach of data infestion consider as "too small data bit" during ingestion which caused fragmentation?

Is it possible 5 million unique values is too much and that is the root cause of slow response?

Answer (score 0):

We've had a latency spike yesterday, and a smaller one today. Can you give project id + job ids of query jobs that took longer than you expected?

Comment: It did complete after 2 hours and 10 minutes.  Hproject id + jobid: atbflow:job_7c07ccb9417a4b34b241ffc2636e234c, start time:  21 May 11:22:14, duration: 2:10:03, bytes processed: 63015028495

Comment: It looks like you may have run this during the temporary query slowdown. I just ran your query and it completed in 11 seconds. Can you let me know if you see any further problems?